# Java dynamic matrix structure

Tags: java, matrix, data-structures

I'm wondering about the best way to implement a matrix in Java in which columns and rows have to be easily added/removed.

Something like `double[][] matrix` seems quite heavy when it comes to column/row removal.

I did some searches but could not find a design pattern (or so) dealing with this. Do you have any suggestion? I'm not looking for a library but more some guidelines on what is needed. I was thinking of a mix of Lists and Maps but I'm not sure that's the most efficient.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246819/dynamic-table-matrix-data-structure-for-java) provides a bit of help but I'm sure there is a design pattern for this, or at least a nice way to do it.

Here are some more specifications: I expect the matrix to be 300x300 big in general. I need to do many manipulations though (I'm doing a heuristic that updates it a lot, hundreds times/sec), thus I can't browse it every time I want to update it. There's no maximum size but I don't expect it to be larger that 5000x5000.

Comment: How big your matrix arrays are gonna be? 10x10 or 10000 X 10000? How often you will change its row/col number? Is there a max marix size?

Comment: I added some more specifications in my questions, thanks.

Comment: When you add/remove cols/rows, is it always on the end?

Comment: No, it can be anywhere, otherwise the array implementation would have been fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible simple solution would be the use of a List of List, like

```
int nRows = 8, nCols = 4;
List<List<Double>> matrix = new ArrayList<>(nRows);
for (int k = 0; k < nRows; k++) {
    matrix.add(new ArrayList<>(nCols));
}
```

In this case would be really easy to add/remove a row, but a little tricky to add/remove a column.

```
void removeRow(ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> matrix, int rowIndexToRemove) {
    matrix.remove(rowIndexToRemove);
}

void removeColumn(ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> matrix, int coulmnIndexToRemove) {
    for (ArrayList<Double> row : matrix) {
        row.remove(coulmnIndexToRemove);
    }
}

void addRow(ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> matrix, int rowIndexWhereInsert, ArrayList<Double> newRow) {
    matrix.add(rowIndexWhereInsert, newRow);
}

void addColumn(ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> matrix, int columnIndexWhereInsert, ArrayList<Double> newColumn) {
    for (int k = 0; k < matrix.size(); k++) {
        ArrayList<Double> row = matrix.get(k);
        row.add(columnIndexWhereInsert, newColumn.get(k));
    }        
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought about that too but it doesn't fit here. maybe I need to be more accurate: I need the same easy access for both. I can't allow to browse the matrix every time I want to update it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to create your own class for this, similar to this

```
class Matrix{
int rows
int cols
List<MatrixElement> elements;
//some methods like getCols(), getRows()
}

class MatrixElement{
int row
int col
double value
//some methods like boolean isNeighbourOf(MatrixElement other) etc whatever you need

}
```

Such thing is quite easy to implement and gives you all the flexibility you need when using

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this implementation [here](https://code.google.com/p/efficient-java-matrix-library/). It looks like what you're looking for.

Comment: Very interesting link, thank you. I may go for it. I don't mark my question as answered yet though, since I'm really curious to know if there's any good practice.
As I mentioned, I'm interested in solving my problem but I'm as much interested in the theoretical/abstract answer: the minimum needed to have a matrix easily updatable.